# React Native - ReactComponentTreeHook.purgeUnmountedComponents is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get this error message when I use `react-native run-ios` or just build for iOS:

```
ReactComponentTreeHook.purgeUnmountedComponents is not a function. (In 'ReactComponentTreeHook.purgeUnountedComponents()', 'ReacComponentTreeHook.purgeUnmountedComponents' is undefined)
```

I have used [CRNA](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) and ejected. I have also used [`react-native-push-notification`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and [`react-native-beacons-manager`](https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager) and followed the instructions of both. The project works when I run it in Android.

I have read [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8454) that it depends on the fact that I am using the minified version of `react` and unminified version of `react-dom` but I don't see where I can change that when it comes to React Native.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end, I figured that the versions of `react` and `react-native` packages that I were installed didn't "match". I saw the message `npm WARN react-native@0.48.4 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.12 but none was installed.` (I had a previous version installed because of another warning that I got).

As soon as I installed `react@16.0.0-alpha.12` instead, the problem was solved. Apparently facebook has removed the function `ReactComponentTreeHook.purgeUnmountedComponents` from the code, it is not to be used anymore.

Comment: This happened to me when using `yarn install` (the packages were correct at `package.json`). Using `npm install` solved the problem.